# A query to show me the number of patients discharged and re-enter within 72 hours for the same cause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2005 I have a table that stores incoming and outgoing patients in a hospital.

Table data stores are: patient's full name, date of admission, date of discharge, and the cause of the entrance to the hospital.

What I need is a query to show me the number of patients discharged and re-enter within 72 hours for the same cause.

the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE hospital(
     patient   varchar(50),    
     in        datetime, 
     out       datetime, 
     reason_id int
 );
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H1.PATIENT 
FROM HOSPITAL H1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM HOSPITAL) H2 ON DATEDIFF(HOUR,H1.IN,H2.OUT) < 72
```

Comment: Can you post the query that [you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: is this homework?  I hope you don't have more than one patient with the same full name...

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT H1.PATIENT FROM HOSPITAL H1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM HOSPITAL) H2 ON DATEDIFF(HOUR,H1.IN,H2.OUT) < 72

Comment: i work in a hispital, i need to do something similar, that's the idea but it't nos the real table.

Comment: If someone is readmitted twice in 72 hours but the middle admission is different (the reasons are A-->B-->A), would this count?

Comment: @Beth, I also work in a hospital and often answer similar questions.  However, I see your point given that there is no medical record number in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct h1.patient
from   Hospital h1 join Hospital h2 on h1.patient = h2.patient
where  h1.[in] < h2.[in]
and    h2.[in] < dateadd(hour, 72, h1.[out])
and    h1.reason_id = h2.reason_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you will select the record where they have been admitted for at least 72hr,right?  so do this;

```
SELECT Patient FROM 
(
SELECT Patient, DATEDIFF ("HH", In,Out)HOURDIFF FROM hospital
)temp 
WHERE HOURDIFF > 72
```

You will need the reason_id field for when the patient is re-admitted and add that to Where clause that way you can filter further to get same admitted and re-admitted reason id.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to look at the *next* admission within 72 hours, then the best bet is to use `lag` . . . assuming you have SQL Server 2012.  Otherwise, this query does the same thing.

Well, I'll describe the answer.  You can use a correlated subquery to get the next reason and next time.  Then a `where` clause to meet the conditions:

```
where nextIn <= DATEADD(hh, 72, out) and
      nextReason = reason
```

[trouble uploading answer]